# SalesForce api: entity type cannot be inserted: Activity History

Tags: salesforce

I have a simple app that pulls members out of sales force via the web reference API.

the only write back is to update ActivityHistory for Mass Mail for each member.

```
var ah = new ActivityHistory();
...
Svc.create(new[] { ah });
```

> Error adding entity: entity type cannot be inserted: Activity History

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActivityHistory is a read-only view of completed activities. So to create a record that would appear in the view, you would need to create an activity (i.e. in the Api a Task or Event) that is marked as completed (or in the past for an event)

Comment: thanks! I'm assuming i'd need Task. how can i indicate type to be "Mass Mail" ? Task.ReocrdType ?